# Hysteresis in the Lorenz Equations

Tags: chaos-theory, non-linear-systems

I was going through Strogatz's wonderful book on nonlinear dynamics and while reading through one problem he posed at the end of the chapter, I did not really understand what was going on. So I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

It states that for the Lorenz equations

$ \frac{dx}{dt}=\sigma(y-x) $

$\frac{dy}{dt} = rx - y - xz$

$\frac{dz}{dt} = xy-bz$

for $ \sigma = 10, b = 8/3,$ 
$\space$

a hysteresis can be seen if we let $r=24.4+sin(\omega t) $ where $ \omega $ is small compared to the typical orbital frequencies on the attractor.

What does he actually mean by that?
And what should I be looking out for or plotting?

I've tried plotting the trajectory ***x vs t, y vs t and z vs t*** and I see that it alternates between chaotic and almost periodic.

[image: Plot of y and z against time, angular frequency is taken at 0.15]

Between about **t = 110 to 120**, ***y*** appears to be chaotic, while ***z*** appears to be periodic.

Is this what Strogatz is talking about in his book?

edit:

as docscience suggested, here is a phase plot of y vs z.

[image]

But I'm not sure if I can see any hysteresis.

Comment: Rather than plotting y and z vs time, I suggest you plot y vs z as a phase plot which may make it easier to see any hysteretic like behavior in the orbits. Nonlinearity in physical systems can result in hysteresis - it's actually required. So I wouldn't be surprised to see it in the Lorentz system.

Comment: Crossposting is not recommended: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1191856/

Comment: What are your initial conditions for $\mathbf x$?

Comment: And also what are you using for $\omega$?

Comment: Ah. I used $\omega $ = 0.15 and initial conditions are [5,0,1] @KyleKanos

Comment: @docscience I've done a phase plot as you've suggested (and have added it above) I'm not sure if I can see hysteresis. Do you see anything?

Comment: There's nothing too different than what I've seen before in the Lorentz phase plots, so I guess I also don't know what this author is referring to when he says there is hysteresis.

Comment: Well hysteresis is the dependence of $\mathbf x(t+dt)$ on $\mathbf x(t)$ (and really all $t\geq0$), so changing $\mathbf x(t=0)$ will change the Lorenz attractor which would seem to obey the hysteresis principle. Why $r=r(t)$ matters here is unclear to me.

Comment: I would guess that your $ω$ is far too big.